# Bitmap as background to MDI mainfrm

Tags: c++, bitmap, background, mfc, mdi

I am trying to make a bitmap image the background for the mainframe before any other frames are loaded but I'm not having any luck, what am I missing?

```
BOOL CMainFrame::OnEraseBkgnd(CDC* pDC)
{
    CBitmap m_cbImage;
    COLORREF m_crBack;
    UINT m_uImage;
    m_crBack = RGB(255, 255, 255);
    m_uImage = IDB_SPLASH;

    if ((m_cbImage.m_hObject == NULL) && (m_uImage>0))
    {
        m_cbImage.LoadBitmap(m_uImage);
        m_bFirst = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        if (m_bFirst)
        {
            m_bFirst = FALSE;
        }
    }
    CRect rcClient;
    GetClientRect(rcClient);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(rcClient, m_crBack);
    if (m_cbImage.m_hObject != NULL)
    {
        BITMAP sBitmap;
        m_cbImage.GetBitmap(&sBitmap);
        CSize szImage(sBitmap.bmWidth, sBitmap.bmHeight);
        pDC->DrawState(CPoint(0, 0), szImage, &m_cbImage, DST_BITMAP | DSS_NORMAL);
    }
    return TRUE;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What looks like the background of the mainframe really isn't. The mainframe mostly just handles exactly that: the frame. The MDI client area is handled by a MDI Client window (which, in turn, manages the MDI child windows).

To change the background drawing, you create a MDI Client window class (public derivative of `CWnd`), and handle the drawing in its `OnEraseBkgnd`. Create an instance of that class in your MainFrame class, and in your MainFrame's `OnCreate`, tell your MDI client to subclass the stock MDI client window:

```
myClient.SubclassWindow(m_hWndMDIClient);
```

Comment: As an example of what you said here, I found here a little code: http://codexpert.ro/blog/2013/01/28/custom-paint-in-mdi-client/

Answer (score 2):

The proposed approach via subclassing doesn't work in latest versions of MFC.
But, fortunately, a special way is designed for such a task:

- ensure your CMainFrame class inherits from `CMDIFrameWndEx`,
- override its `OnEraseMDIClientBackground( CDC* dc )` virtual method,
- your implementation should return `TRUE`.